# hover multiples add class to common parent container instances

Tags: jquery

Apologies for being newbish!

I wish to add/remove class on a parent container div when any of say 3 child elements are hovered, regardless of nesting structure.
This is so I can apply CSS styles to any child elements of their respective nearest common parent container on hover.

```html
$('.beta').hover(function(){
   $('.alpha').toggleClass('hover');
});

$('.beta2').hover(function(){
   $('.alpha2').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/skL828kz/

As you can see in the .js portion of the demo, I have 2 seperate functions.
Functionality works great for me, but I was wondering how I would re-write this for multiple instances (more than X2).

Comment: Can you indent your code, please?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... why can't you just name  `beta2` and `alpha2` as `beta` and `alpha`, just like in the first group? That would work without the 2nd javascript event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  That would probably work too, I'll have to try it in production.  The things is, now both (all) the parent containers are affected with the generated class_name.  I only need 1 at any given time.  Wouldn't this be overkill?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shaun1031/skL828kz/3/

Answer (score 2):

Based on this https://jsfiddle.net/shaun1031/skL828kz/3/

Change the JQuery code to

```
$('.beta').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('.alpha').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

OR

```
$('.beta').hover(function(){
    $(this).parents('.alpha').toggleClass('hover');
});
```